# Published asp.net site back to solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a published asp.net website on a server and I need to get this back into a solution for editing etc. Are there any tools out there which would give me back the solution?

[Ilspy](http://ilspy.net/) did not do this for me,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are your views precompiled as well? That can pose some level of pain, if you want to modify compiled views

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan No the views are OK

Comment: Well, in that caseI second @Habib.

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan JustDecompile was not very good, is.net reflector any better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had good experience with [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

Comment: This one worked the best for me however I have not tried .Net Reflector being now its not free. Thanks for everyone's comments

Answer (score 2):

You should look for .Net Decompiler tools.

[Decompiler tools for .NET Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amb/archive/2011/05/24/decompiling-tools-for-net-framework.aspx)

Some of the popular tools are:

- [.NET Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/)
- [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) (free)

Comment: JustDecompile produces a mess and a lot of irrelevant code. .Net is not free, do you have experience with this one and is it any good? Thanks

Comment: @CR41G14, you will not get the exact code by any decompilers, and there would be all other things done by the compiler e.g. Compile time optimization etc. I have used .Net Reflector, It is similar to ILSpy

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only have the compiled versions of the pages, this can get really tricky.

You will need to use a decompiler on each assembly. Easy decompilers to use are, like Habib already suggested, .NET Reflector and JustDecompile. If you are already using **ReSharper**, the current version has a decompiler (**dotPeek**) built-in and you can also download that separately, for free, at http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler.

The problem is that decompilers don't really reconstruct your code exactly as it was originally, and you may still have to modify things by hand. This is especially true if the code was compiled with the "Optimize code" setting set to `true`.

Good luck!