# Extract code files from deployed website

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have got a website running on the IIS server. Somehow lost the original source code files that were created within visual studio.

In the deployed folder within production I can only see .aspx files but cannot view the .cs files.
There are couple of DLLS containing classes that I need to retrieve code from.

How can I retrieve code files from deployed folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [decompiling an asp.net site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153664/decompiling-an-asp-net-site)

Comment: Or [Published asp.net site back to solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233809/published-asp-net-site-back-to-solution).

Comment: Hi,i have got reflector and file generator plug in installed. which files should i get from production, is it all files from bin folder  or deployment.dll. what about other .aspx files etc